# Selenium IE Webdriver stuck at "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server." with IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using remote driver on VM Windows 8 32bits, so I used IEWebDriver for 32bits, and IE11 (Version: 11.0.9600.18053). Whenever I run test, it always goes to a random localhost URL and says :

> This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.

and from the test report it says:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Browser zoom level was set to 200%. It should be set to 100%

I have searched and tried a couple of solutions on here, but none of them worked:

- I disabled IE debugger
- I enabled the same "Enable Protected Mode" for each zone
- I changed the zoom level to 100% by Control Panel/Display set to small (100%) but the problem is still here
- I search that windows updates packages breaks IE driver, but I couldn't find KB3025390 in the updated list, and my windows is just updated today, it is a fresh VM

Any other solutions please. Thanks

Comment: If you've already set zoom to 100% and set the same "Enable Protected Mode" for all zones, the only other thing that I do, besides those, is adding the URL of the site I'm going to test to the "Trusted Sites" zones. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: I had already added the site to Trusted Sites zones, but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set the wrong zoom level. The zoom level in the Control Panel is a system-wide setting; you want the one for IE alone. Launch Internet Explorer manually, and on your keyboard, type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (zero). That's the keyboard shortcut for restoring the zoom level to 100%. Alternatively, you could choose the 100% zoom level from the menu, but I don't remember if that's available directly off the menus you see from the gear icon, or if you have to enable the full menu bar.

You could also set the `ignoreZoomLevel` capability to false, but clicking on elements is likely to fail. The driver will be miscalculating the coordinates at which to click if the zoom level isn't properly set.

Comment: For some reason, Ctr + 0 set my zoom level to 200%, maybe I am using Parallels VM for Mac. Anyway, I fixed the problem with the setting capability.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true); and the clicking on elements is correct as driver calculates the coordinates correctly. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Enabled the same "Enable Protected Mode" for each zone
Changed the zoom level to 100% by Control Panel/Display set to small (100%)

If after setting up all above mentioned if problem still exist ,check IE Driver Version and selenium webdriver version. if both are different its not going to work. Download latest version of both webdriver as well as IE Driver and try. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

So in capybara framework written in Ruby this is how its solved 
instead of calling it capabilities or desired_capabilites( how every the case syntax
your programming language desires) you need to call it options

According to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities
they are named desired capabilities, but when you examine them they are command line options (undocumented documentation). You will notice this when you make a driver 
with an options key as in key ,value pair and it complains about the type or missing the properties listed in the website link.

By enabling this you can run your tests at whichever IE Zoom level you please, 100% is not the correct zoom level for realtime webapps for IE its scaled to 150% as a quick fix to comply with the modern standard. So in addition do not create responsiveness around browser zoom levels, very bad ending

feel free to reach out

```html
Capybara.register_driver :remote_chrome do |app|
  a = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {
    :browser              => :ie,
    :options => Selenium::WebDriver::IE::Options.new({
      :ignore_zoom_levels => true,
      :ignore_zoom_setting => true, 
      :javascript_enabled => true
    }),
  })
  
end
```